# Architecture of android custom library

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, return-value

I am building an android library. 
The main class includes methods like `connect`,`getUserSession` .Workflow includes few steps-

Step 1 :
In `getUserSession` method. I need to send a `Http` POST request to external api and 
recieve the response data(sessionKey,id,name etc). It is like an authentication method.

Step 2 :
In connect method. It uses the response data from Step 1 then I need to connect to `websocket` server recieve the response data(userdetails,profilepic etc).

Step3 :
Pass the response data from Step 2 in Activity.

I want to be step 1 and step 2 to be synchrounous because step 2 won't work without step 1. And i dont want to block the app while processing.After doing some research i found this can be done using **AsyncTask** class. But it seems i cannot return values from `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` methods. How to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set listener (interface) for first **AsyncTask**  Please try below code

```
  interface AsyncTaskListener{
     public void onTaskCompleted(Object<Type> value);
  }

  public class DemoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
  AsyncTaskListener listener;
  public  DemoAsyncTask(AsyncTaskListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
   ///do some task 
    return someResult;
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
  }
```

//Calling Async task from activity or fragment

```
DemoAsyncTask task = new DemoAsyncTask(new AsyncTaskListener(){
@Override
public void on onTaskCompleted(Object<Type> value);{
//do your second step here
})
};
task .execute();
```

Comment: Thanks,Simple and clean. much appreciated !

Comment: Hi , can you give some good source to learn about this technique?

Comment: http://android-dwivediji.blogspot.in/2014/01/best-way-to-use-asynctask-class.html check this